# Filter then map instances from a stream and other Java 8 hiccups

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time rewriting this method to something more legible and understandable for the reader.

```
static Stream<Class<? extends MyType>> collectMyTypes(Object o) {
  return Reflection.lineage(o.getClass())
      .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
      .map(Field::getGenericType)
      .filter(t -> t instanceof ParameterizedType)
      .map(t -> (ParameterizedType) t)
      .filter(t -> t.getRawType() == MyTypeWrapper.class)
      .map(t -> t.getActualTypeArguments()[0]) //MyTypeWrapper is final and has only 1 type argument.
      .filter(t -> t instanceof Class)
      .map(t -> (Class<? extends MyType>) t);
}
```

Here are the tools/classes I use:

- `Reflection.lineage(Class<T>)` iterates over all parents classes of `T`;
- `MyTypeWrapper` is defined as `final class MyTypeWrapper<T extends MyType>`;
- `MyType` is defined as `abstract class MyType`.

What annoys me with this code is that it's barely legible, mostly because of the succession of filter on instance then map. I tried to find in Java 8  something similar to Guava's [`Iterables.filter(Iterable<?>,Class<T>)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class)) but haven't found any (yet, I implemented a similar method, but the code then looks like Lisp). Also, the call to `Arrays.stream` disturbs me. Yeah, I could split it into `.map(Class::getDeclaredFields).flatten(Arrays::stream)` but this would add some unnecessary complexity, wouldn't it?

Anyways, any input is welcome.

Given the example below, this method will keep/skip various fields.

```
class GoodExample extends MyType {}
class BadExample extends MyType {}
class Example {

  // GoodExample will be returned.
  MyTypeWrapper<GoodExample> object1; 

  // BadExample will be skipped because the type is a wildcard
  MyTypeWrapper<? extends BadExample> object2;

  // There is no type to return so this field is skipped.
  MyTypeWrapper object3;

  // This is not an instance of MyTypeWrapper so it's skipped.
  Object object4;

  // This is generic, but still not a MyTypeWrapper, so it's skipped.
  List<BadExample> object5;
}
```

*Edit*:

Originally the method was this:

```
  List<Class<? extends MyType>> types = new ArrayList<>();
  Reflection.lineage(o.getClass())
      .forEach((c) -> {
        for (Field f: c.getDeclaredFields()) {
          Type type = f.getGenericType();
          if (!(type instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
            continue;
          }
          ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)type;
          if (pType.getRawType() != MyTypeWrapper.class) {
            continue;
          }
          // length is 1.
          Type argType = pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
          if (!(argType instanceof Class)) {
            continue;
          }
          Class<? extends MyType> argClass = (Class<? extends MyType>)argType;
          types.add(argClass);
        }
      });
return types;
```

Comment: I don't think this is worth an answer, but have you considered moving away from the Stream-Based approach and just return a `List<Class<? extends MyType>>`? This seems to be the cleanest solution to me ...

Comment: @Vogel612 Actually, I did. I've updated the question with the code as it was. What disturbed me was the recurring type-related variable names which lead to confusion. As well as the ugly and repeated not-instanceof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can suggest is putting the subsequent `filter()`/`map()` steps into an extraction method of sorts:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static Optional<Type> extractMyType(Field field) {
    return Optional.of(field.getGenericType())...;
}
```

You can also put the `filter()`/`map()` steps as a single method:

```
private static <T, R> Optional<R> filterAndMap(T obj, Predicate<? super T> filter,
        Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return Optional.of(obj).filter(filter).map(mapper);
}
```

For convenience, you can create a `cast()` method that calls `filterAndMap()` to handle *safe*-casting:

```
private static <T, R> Optional<R> cast(T obj, Class<R> clazz) {
    return filterAndMap(obj, clazz::isInstance, v -> (R) obj);
}
```

Then, the meat of `extractMyType()` effectively becomes three `flatMap()` operations:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static Optional<Class> extractMyType(Field field) {
    return Optional.of(field.getGenericType())
            .flatMap(v -> cast(v, ParameterizedType.class))
            .flatMap(v -> filterAndMap(v,
                            v1 -> v1.getRawType() == MyTypeWrapper.class,
                            v1 -> v1.getActualTypeArguments()[0]))
            .flatMap(v -> cast(v, Class.class));
}
```

Finally, your `collectMyTypes()` method will just do a simple filter on the resulting `Optional` wrapper instances:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static Stream<Class<? extends MyType>> collectMyTypes(Object o) {
    return Reflection.lineage(o.getClass())
            .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(YourClass::extractMyType).filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get);
}
```

Comment: `getActualTypeArgument` can return a `WildcardType`. Those are explicitly excluded from my method, not from yours. I can't accept or even upvote this. Though, I'll show an example of what this should filter/return. Note that `==` on `Class` instances is safe (given that `Class` is final and doesn't override `equals`).

Comment: Though, I have to say I really like the `extractComponent` idea.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire got what you mean... see updated answer.

Comment: Indeed, it is very similar to what I came to based on your initial answer. I still dislike it somehow and might keep the `collectMyTypes` as you wrote it and write `extractMyType` in plain (no java 8 fancy stuff). But well, it now answers the question and provides java 8 alternative, so well done, you get the accepted answer! :)